# Count individual combination of two variables between two columns

Tags: r, variables, count, combinations

I want to count the individual combination of two variables between two columns, for making a barplot or pie chart afterwards.

Here the example:

```
dat <- read.csv2(file = textConnection("a;b
x;no
x;yes
x;no
x;yes
x;yes
y;no
y;no
x;yes
x;no
y;yes
y;yes
y;no
y;yes
y;yes
x;no
x;yes"))
```

From this data I want a table/number whatever with the number of the "x" from column "a" answered with an "yes" from column "b". So here in this example there should be the number of five "x" with the combination of an "yes".
Hepofully its understandable. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Did you try `table(dat)` or `nrow(dat[ dat$a == "x" & dat$b == "yes", ])`? is the expected output just 5?

Comment: Maybe you want: `barplot(table(dat$a, dat$b), legend = TRUE)
`?